# Dictionaries<K, V> in Freezables

Tags: c#, wpf, freezable

I want to create a `Freezable` that contains a Dictionary as one `DependencyProperty`. So I think I need a `freezable Dictionary` because it must not be changed when the `Freezable` gets frozen... or am I wrong? If so what do I really have to do?

Comment: Is it an option for you to just use an `ILookup` instead of a `Dictionary`?  It's immutable.

Comment: Yes, it would be an option for accessing the entries; but then how do I set the values?

Comment: You call `ToLookup` on some other data structure or `IEnumerable` that has all of the needed information.

Comment: Right, but I hoped there would be an easier solution...

Comment: You can create your own implementation of the interface if there is some other method more amenable to your particular application.  There are no other concrete implementations in the BCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it is possible to use a Lookup, I finally ended up writing a FreezableDictionary so that I do not get IEnumerables as I would using a Lookup. It uses a simple Dictionary as a backing.